# how to install Tableau in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, visualization, tableau-api

Is there any sudo-alike magic spell to install Tableau or the only solution is by using it via the web app?

Somehow, didn't find the installation pack for Tableau. Any other Tableau-alike solution for ubuntu recommended is also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau Desktop is only available for PC or MAC. Tableau Server is available for linux https://www.tableau.com/products/linux

Comment: Thanks, I thought so... anyhow, fine with the statement